# QGIS background images production date

Tags: qgis

I am creating shapefile of buildings based on QGIS background images and need to add information  on the final shapefile about the source and date at which these images were taken.

Can anyone tell me how to know production date of images used as background in QGIS?

Comment: What do you call background images ? if that's some layer you add from openlayer or Quickmapservice plugin you need to check with the original provider (and be aware that some provider may restrict certain use...)